# Is my Matlab code correct for applying PCA to data?

Tags: matlab, classification, pca

I have following code for calculating PCA in Matlab:

```
train_out = train';
test_out = test';
% subtract off the mean for each dimension
mn = mean(train_out,2);
train_out = train_out - repmat(mn,1,train_size);
test_out = test_out - repmat(mn,1,test_size);
% calculate the covariance matrix
covariance = 1 / (train_size-1) * train_out * train_out';
% find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues
[PC, V] = eig(covariance);
% extract diagonal of matrix as vector
V = diag(V);
% sort the variances in decreasing order
[junk, rindices] = sort(-1*V);
V = V(rindices);
PC = PC(:,rindices);
% project the original data set
out = PC' * train_out;
train_out = out';
out = PC' * test_out;
test_out = out';
```

Train and test matrix have observations in rows and feature variables in columns. When I perform classification on original data (without PCA) I get much better results than with PCA, even when I keep all dimensions. When I tried doing PCA directly on the whole dataset (train + test) I noticed correlation between these new principal components and previous ones are either near 1 or near -1 which I find strange. I am probably doing something wrong but just can't figure it out.

Comment: is there some limitation that you can not use svd? http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/svd.html

Comment: No limitation, but output should be the same, right? Guess I can try another implementation to see what I get.

Comment: As for as I know, this is kind of the standard way to do PCA in MATLAB. So, unless you want to tweak the procedure, I think it's easier to just use this. Because it looks something went wrong in your PCA calculation, I hope svd give you sound results.

Comment: I tried three more implementations and they all give same numbers, only method I posted here had different sign for some principal components. Still that should mean they do the job correctly. I just don't get it why classification gives much lower accuracy on different datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct, however using princomp function my be easier:

```
train_out=train; % save original data
test_out=test;
mn = mean(train_out);
train_out = bsxfun(@minus,train_out,mn); % substract mean
test_out = bsxfun(@minus,test_out,mn);
[coefs,scores,variances] = princomp(train_out,'econ'); % PCA
pervar = cumsum(variances) / sum(variances);
dims = max(find(pervar < var_frac)); % var_frac - e.g. 0.99 - fraction of variance explained
train_out = train_out*coefs(:,1:dims); % dims - keep this many dimensions
test_out = test_out*coefs(:,1:dims); % result is in train_out and test_out
```